# Dynamically produce html based on templates

Tags: html, email, templates, newsletter

I am trying to automate a workflow for automatically creating HTML newsletters based on information stored in a spreadsheet.

Currently, I am using a newsletter drag and drop tool, in which several pre-programmed blocks are available (e.g. full column block, 2 column block etc). When creating a newsletter, I drag and drop a block and fill in my content (e.g. uploading an image, inserting a url). This is all well and good, however, since I have to create the same newsletter in 10 different languages, this process is quiet time consuming and prone to human error. While all newsletters are the same in terms of layout, the images and urls differ.

To solve this issue, I would like to get rid of the drag and drop process, and instead automate the workflow in some other way.

One idea that I have already tried, but that doesn't seem like the perfect option to me, is to dynamically create the needed HTMLs in Excel. Basically, the idea is to take the existing block template structure, and put it into Excel with some formulas.

I could then copy and paste the links to the images (in a simple format, such as EN1.jpg, ES1.jpg, etc.), as well as to urls (url.com, url.es).

This is some example block:

```
<a href="URL" target="_blank"><img alt="" align="center" width="700" style="max-width:700px;"  class="resetWidth" border="0"  src="IMAGE" /></a>
```

My final expected result is something like this:

I define the layout in a very quick manner (e.g. writing fullcolumn, half column, fullcolumn). The corresponding code is taken from the template. I then provide the attributes (image url, link url) in the form of a list or so. The end result should then be 10 html files that I simply have to upload to the newsletter software.

I would appreciate it very much if anyone had any ideas on this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for translating the page is to do something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp 
it adds a selection for languages to translate into.

As for automating the images, you could set up folders for each langauge and reuse the name of images based on where you want them so they would be placed in the correct location. 
All you'll have to do it replace the images with the same file names and swap the default language on the Google Translator.

So something like this that the html will stay the same with regards to the image names [image: Directory]

For the link variables you may be able to write some JS or another language to take advantage of the

```
 <html lang="">
```

and based on which lang is set, insert a set of links to the file.